# OpenVPN multiple configurations

Tags: openvpn

I have OpenVPN setup to route all traffic through the VPN. I am wondering if there is a way to switch whether all traffic is routed or just traffic destined for that network per client.

For example, if I am on an untrusted network, I want all my traffic routed through the VPN. Later however when on a trusted network I may just want SSH access to machines, but do not want all traffic routed since it would be unnecessarily slow.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but this is controlled from the server side. Which is not quite what you are asking for.

Comment: Right, exactly. So my question was if there was a way to do this client side. Perhaps have different configurations for different client keys or something?

Comment: Sorry, cant comment yet. Can you just have different conf with different up and down scripts that stablish or not default route? That may give you the hability to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the idea of deleting a route proposed by @MadHatter, I created an alias that does essentially this:

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/config --route-nopull
sudo ip route add x.x.x.x/24 dev tun0
```

Where `x.x.x.x/24` is the path of the internal network you are connecting to through the VPN.

Now I can use this alias when I want only traffic for the internal network to be VPNed, and use the config without `--route-nopull` if I want all traffic to be routed through the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

If the server publishes a default route to you, you may ignore it, with eg

```
route delete default tun0
```

and you can restore your pre-vpn-connection default route similarly.

If on the other hand the server doesn't publish such a route, you may opt to route all your traffic over the VPN, though in this case you will need to ensure that (a) the VPN server is equipped to deal with this, and knows how to NAT/route your traffic to the internet, and deal with the replies, and (b) ensure that you don't have multiple default routes, and that you can still reach the VPN endpoint.

In short, assuming you control your client, you control *inter alia* its routing tables, and you can set them up how you like.  Routing *less* to the server than it might wish is easy; routing *more* than it might require needs its cooperation, or at least its capability; but both are possible.

Comment: It doesn't look like I am getting a default route. There are a bunch of other routes that it is pushing though.